# MySQL throws error on Yii2 migration, doesn't in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, yii2

In one of my migrations, I add a column 'dateCreated' to all tables. This works fine for most tables, but throws a strange error on some of them:

`'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'start_date' at row 1
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE`payments`ADD`dateCreated`DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL'`

A column 'start_date' exists already, but I can't see why this has anything to do with the newly created column.
This breaks my migration. The same SQL works fine when applied directly on the table in PhpMyAdmin. Does Yii add extra checks to the query, or am I missing something else?

This is the complete migration:

```
public function up()
    $tableNames = Yii::$app->db->schema->tableNames;

    foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand('ALTER TABLE '.$tableName.' ENGINE = InnoDB')->query();
    }
}
```

Comment: write a separate migration for alter table then check.

Comment: This IS a separate migration for alter table. It now seems, that even if I go around Yii's DB Connection and just use mysqli, I get the same error. Sequel Pro doesn't throw the error and just let's me alter the table...

Comment: is there any insert command in your migration , if yes check it  for start_date column .

Comment: I've added the migration code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your migration.

**1)** Migration should interact with database structure and data related with time it was added, not current time.

When you write this:

`Yii::$app->db->schema->tableNames;`

you are referring to all existing tables at the moment of running migration.

So imagine if you add some new tables later and you don't need that column for some tables. If your new teammate will run migrations or it will be run on new server, the `dateCreated` will be added to all tables. If it was other operation, for example delete, this can lead to serious problems, for example unexpected data loss.

So remember - always operate with database structure and data related with moment of creating migration.

I recommend to create private static array for example and use it in both `up()` and `down()` methods.

```
private static $_tableNames = [
    'tableName1',
    'tableName2',
];
```

**2)** When there are many queries, it will be more safely to wrap it in transaction. Use `safeUp()` and `safeDown()` methods instead. In this case if migration will fail on certain query, rollback will be applied and you don't have to do any additional manual manipulations with database.

**3)** There is no need to write raw SQL for such common tasks in migration. Use `yii\db\Migration` methods.

**4)** `yii\db\Command` `query()` is used for selection, for deletion use `execute()`. But no need to use it, because there is shortcut in migrations for executing raw SQL: `$this->execute('YOUR SQL GOES HERE')`.

**5)** I'd recommend to use undescore (`_`) as separator in column names, but it's not crucial.

So finally you migration will look something like this:

```
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\db\Migration;

class m111111_111111_add_date_created_column_to_all_existing_tables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * @var array List of table names
     */
    private static $_tableNames = [
        'tableName1',
        'tableName2',
    ],

    public function safeUp()
    {   
        foreach (self::$_tableNames as $table) {
            $this->addColumn($table, 'date_created', $this->dateTime()->defaultValue(new yii\db\Expression('NULL')));
        }
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {   
        foreach (self::$_tableNames as $table) {
            $this->dropColumn($table, 'date_created');
        }
    }
}
```

This is more like a code review, but back to the main problem: in the provided code there is no addition of `dateCreated` column at all (in fact no changes at all) and the error related with `start_date` comes from different part.

The logic of such queries:

```
ALTER TABLE payments ADD dateCreated DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

is correct, as a result `dateCreated` column will be added to all listed table names.

Existing rows will be filled with `NULL` data (for `dateCreated` column), so there is no chance for values like `0000-00-00` to appear (also it's datetime, not date). `start_date` is a different column, check the logic related with it in other place of code.

Comment: Alter table doesn't have a common method. I use common methods in the provided example to add columns.

Comment: You need to use `addColumn` and `dropColumn` for adding and dropping columns accordingly, they both contain `ALTER TABLE` part inside.